# How to count number of occurrences of a unique number in MySQL/php

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to make a table that lists the number of unique numbers in a sequence. Currently it is just listing the data and not sorting it.

For example, the table is currently listing all the dates I am putting in but if I put in (2001, 2, 23), (2001, 2, 2), (2001, 2, 6) It would just spit out the dates. I want it to list the days as "3" because I listed three different unique days.

I've got no idea how to fix this. Would the count function work?

Answer (score 0):

Although your question must be clarified, Sounds like simple `group by`

```
select count(*) uniqueCount
from
    (select mydate from table group by mydate) T
```

```php
$sql = "select count(*) uniqueCount from (select mydate from table group by mydate) T";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "Count: " . $row["uniqueCount"];
  }
} else {
  echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: thanks  - not my downvote unfortunately so I can't retract it...

Comment: @Nick no problem. at least the question has an answer